# Palantir Foundry - Slate Dashboard - Sync error

Tags: data-analysis, palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

I have a Slate Dashboard Developed in Foundry.
Until last week, I had no issues in plotting the data to the dashboard graphs that were created.

**The Issue:**
Unfortunately, in the past 5 days when we try to load the Slate Dashboard, we are unable to see the data getting plotted.

What I tried to do is:

1. Try to check if the Postgres syncs are getting updated correctly. **They are fine. No issues there.**
2. Query the sync from Slate "Queries" tab. Unfortunately, **it failed with a Status Code: 500**

[image: Error Code]

**More Info:**
More elaborately, I have synced the dataset that I have created in Foundry to Postgres SQL. This is done inorder to enable SQL querying of the dataset while creating Slate Dashboard. These syncs are taken care of by Palantir.

Has someone faced it before?

If yes, it would be really helpful if you can guide me resolving this issue.

Comment: There's not enough info here for anyone to give you an answer, but here are some suggestions for how to get more info: (1) check your console and network tabs in your browser to see if there's any details about that request; (2) share what type of data store the query hits; (3) check that other applications in Foundry are able to query/use that same backing data store (e.g. if it's an object in the ontology, can you load that object in Object Explorer?)

Comment: @Ontologize: I have edited the question with details about the Postgres sync that is created for the dataset. That is the datastore the query hits. I have also checked the other applications in Foundry which hits the same & similar syncs, they do not seem to work either. In addition, I have also raised an incident to Foundry support. Waiting for their response too.

As an additional info, even if we create a new sync and try to query the sync, they are not working. I guess there is some issue on the Palantir Foundry Platform. Let's see how it goes.

Comment: Ok, Palantir support is probably the solution to this. One additional comment for anyone reading this in the future. If you're syncing datasets to Postgres, you can check (a) the syncs tab on a particular dataset, which should indicate whether it was able to sync recently, and (b) check for syncs to postgres in the Builds app (make sure to un-toggle the option that shows just your builds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was precisely an `internal permission error` (or) you can also say `a handshake service was broken`.

> It was an issue at the Foundry Platform's end.

Raised a ticket and the Foundry support team resolved the issue in 2 days.

EDIT: More specifically, looks like it was an infra issue due to a special config file that was used for Slate Application which caused the issue.